# Could someone please give some scenarios for the usage of "despite my money"?

Tags: word-usage

This video (https://youtu.be/UFuxlnUeGmg?t=399) gives an easy-to-use example about the usage of "despite".

> "Despite the peacefulness of the country, I prefer the city."

and then gives this

> "Despite my money"

I cannot even imagine in what situation I would use this expression. So I googled "despite my money" and got this

> My quota dropped from 100 GB to 15 GB despite my money continuing to be paid.

Which sounds reasonable. Could someone please give more scenarios for the usage of "despite my money"?

Comment: Money should be paid, not payed.

Comment: @stevekeiretsu Thanks for your reminder. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"despite my money she didn't love me"

It is a somewhat weird construction as "my money" implies that you have a decent amount of it and to indicate this you would usually use "my wealth".

Similar to using "despite the water" instead of "despite the rain": not *wrong* but kind of strange.

If you google on ["despite my wealth"](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNQg9ypd7Hqz6SFDamcvzPSIgDoXpw%3A1581928277240&source=hp&ei=VU9KXtbzC46VsAee64CYBg&q=%22despite%20my%20wealth%22) you get a number of examples.

Comment: Thank you so much. I went through the first page of your link, which is very helpful. "despite my wealth" indicates that the speaker is supposed to be wealthy, right?

Comment: Yup! if they were poor you could use "despite my lack of money" or "despite my poverty"